# Higher order function Python walkthrough

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

```
def tracer(fn):
    def traced(x):
        print('Calling', fn, '(', x, ')')
        result = fn(x)
        print('Got', result, 'from', fn, '(', x, ')')
        return result
    return traced

def fact(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    return n * fact(n-1)

new_fact = tracer(fact)
new_fact(2)
```

I used this code on pythontutor.com to better understand higher order functions, but i'm having difficulty understanding why `new_fact(2)` in step 8 is mapped to `traced`? In other words, how does the `traced` function know the argument is `2`?

Comment: `new_fact` is `traced`. `tracer` returns it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, functions are objects too. When you call the `tracer()` function, it returns the nested `traced()` function; it is in fact creating a new copy of that function:

```
return traced
```

You stored that returned function object in `new_fact`, then called it:

```
>>> tracer(fact)
<function traced at 0x10644c320>
>>> new_fact = tracer(fact)
>>> new_fact
<function traced at 0x10644c398>
>>> new_fact(2)
('Calling', <function fact at 0x10644c230>, '(', 2, ')')
('Got', 2, 'from', <function fact at 0x10644c230>, '(', 2, ')')
2
```

You can do this with any function; store a reference to a function in another name:

```
>>> def foo(): print 'foo'
... 
>>> bar = foo
>>> bar()
foo
```

Comment: To be precise, `tracer` returns the function `traced()` *bound* to the value of `fn` passed as a parameter. This is how `traced()` remember that it must call `fact()`.

Comment: so since traced is defined within tracer, and when new_fact was set to tracer(fact), it immediately pointed to the traced function when new_fact(2) was called?

Comment: The moment you assigned the return value of `traced` to `new_fact`, that name refers to the function object. Then adding `(2)` behind the name calls (invokes) the function referenced by that name.