# How does Python run inner functions?

Tags: python, function, python-decorators

I am having difficulties in understanding on how inner functions are run in Python. Please have a look at the following snipped of code:

```
def f(a, b):
    return a + b

def outer(f):
    def inner(x, y):
        if not isinstance(x, int) and not isinstance(y, int):
            raise TypeError('Please provide integer for both arguments')
        return f(x, y)
    return inner
```

I am just confused about when `inner` is run and how it returns the function `f` with `inner` 's arguments and lastly the return of `inner` is returning the `f`.

Can anyone enlighten the way Python interprets the steps when the above code is passed to the interpreter.

Comment: Your indentation appears to be off.

Comment: In the code you provided, `inner` is never run. And unless your indentation is off, `inner` doesn't return anything.

Comment: The indentation is fixed now. I'd like to have step by step explanation of how the program runs

Comment: In particular, see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18287297/5014455) and [this very extensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/5014455)

Comment: Also, note, the program you have above simply defines two functions, and never calls a single function. So the answer to "when is `inner` run" is *never*.